# Display node's languages in views

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

do you think, it is possible to display in views the languages the node was translated to?
I mean something like this:

First article
english|german

Second article
english|german|dutch

Comment: Have you tried to implement my answer?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes it is possible.**

I have done something similar in Drupal 7 some time ago. Here is how to do it:

**Create your View**

Create a `Fields` style View with your required filters and sorting

**Add the relationship to the Translations**

1. Add a `relationship` to the translations: `Content translation: Translations`
2. As `Translation option` choose `All`
3. Add a filter `Content translation: Language` and choose `Current user's language`

**Add the Fields**

2. Add the field `Content: Title` with no relation and with `Link this field to the original piece of content` disabled
3. Add the field `Content translation: Language` with the `Translations` relation added before and with `Link this field to the original piece of content` enabled
4. In the `Format Settings` choose `Content: Title` as Grouping Field

**Format the list**

The horizontal list of the languages can be achieved by CSS formatting