# Views + entity translation - show list of translated languages

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I need a view in table format for an administration page, next to each node I want a list of the currently translated languages in it's own table cell. It would look like:

```
title  |  languages
node1  |  english
node2  |  english, chinese
```

I have seen this post which does it by grouping (which I don't want):

[Display node's languages in views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9413/display-nodes-languages-in-views)

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535784/view-of-nodes-and-their-translations), which I can't seem to get to work (filtering by source language does nothing - presumably as it doesn't use entity translation?):

Any idea how this can be done?